# Is it possible to rewrite this XSD in a simpler way?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XSD to validate incoming requests to my api:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0"
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="request">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="amenity">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

But it seems kind of cluttered. Too many nested elements etc. Is it possible to rewrite it in a simpler, less confusing way?

Comment: it doesn't look too bad to me, as in general XSD tends to be verbose. My advice, Don't change it if it works.

Comment: That's about as simple as XML Schema gets....

Comment: You could use `<xs:all/>` instead of `<xs:sequence/>`. In your case it wouldn't matter and you safe 20 overall characters ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it so deeply nested, you can change the complex types to be named types and then refer to them by name from the element declarations. That has benefits in that the types can then be reused. But it won't make this simple schema any simpler...

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is an alternative way ..

It is to define each entity as a ComplexType give it a name, and use as a TYPE :)

here is ur sample xml and xsd

**XML:**

```
<request>
  <amenity>
    <description>text</description>
  </amenity>
</request>
```

**XSD**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="request" type="request"/>

  <xs:complexType name="request">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="amenity" type="amenity"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>  

    <xs:complexType name="amenity">
      <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

Some more explanation:
**suppose your xml is like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<request>
  <amenity>
    <description>text</description>
    <foo>text</foo>
  </amenity>
  <foobar>
    <amenity2>
      <description>text2</description>
      <foo>text3</foo>
    </amenity2>
  </foobar>
</request>
```

Your XSD would be really simpler .. because you don't have to define `<descirption/>` and `<foo/>` tags two times :) 

 observe that I am using `Type="General"` multiple times :)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="request" type="request"/>

  <xs:complexType name="request">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="amenity" type="General"/>
      <xs:element name="foobar" type="foobar"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="General">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="description" type="xs:string" />
      <xs:element name="foo" type="xs:string" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="foobar">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="amenity2" type="General"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```